# Looping an array inside or outside of app.get in expressJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, variables

When the array "hikes" of some objects key-value including inside the app.get() method and pushing some new objects key-value to the array "hikes" then its not looping more than one, means not pushing more than one but when the array "hikes" placing outside the app.get() method that new objects key-value pairs being pushed more than one or looping more.

```
let hikes = [
        {name: 'Blue Mountain', image: 'https://picsum.photos/id/866/400/400'},
        {name: 'Snowy Set', image: 'https://picsum.photos/id/571/400/400'},
        {name: 'Foots on Sand', image: 'https://picsum.photos/id/156/400/400'},
        {name: 'Fog', image: 'https://picsum.photos/id/809/400/400'}
    ]

app.get("/hikes", (req, res) => {   
    let imageName = req.query.name;
    let imageURL = req.query.url;
    let hikesObj = {name: imageName, image: imageURL}

    hikes.push(hikesObj)
    res.render("hikes", {data: hikes})
})
```

Comment: Not that clear what you are asking. But **inside** I presume to be a **local** declaration which means the whole array gets re-instantiated on every call to the `app.get()`, so changes don't persist. **Outside** *would* persists changes, however this will only last until the application restarts. Which would probably be on every code change you are making. What's not really clear is if it is the **scoping** or **persistence** part you are not understanding. Or indeed both. You could probably show the actual code demonstrating the difference of *inside* and *outside* to what you actually mean

Comment: Sorry, i really don't know what should i ask for this doubt and how to brief it. But you got it what i want to know and i have understand. Thanks for your answer! It helped me.

Comment: You seem to be talking about two variations of code, so show **both** listings in the question. Then just **show** the expected result, and also what you really get. **Showing** works best when you don't really understand how to explain it.

Comment: I am very new to here! And its really hard to ask my first question here. Your suggestions will help me for further questions.